# Actors are getting lost when drop failed -libgdx

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, libgdx

I am working on a rummikub game, I have a board which have tiles on it, and all positions on board are defined as TileActor. Some tile actors have actual tiles on them, some are empty. Problem is: when I drag a tile and drop it on an empty TileActor, it works fine but when I drop it on empty space, the actor is getting lost. How can I prevent the actors from getting lost?

**This is my drag&drop code:**

```
dragAndDrop.addSource(new Source(actor) {   
        @Override
        public Payload dragStart(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            Payload payload = new Payload();
            payload.setObject("Some payload!");
            payload.setDragActor(getActor());

            Label validLabel = new Label("Valid move!", skin);
            validLabel.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
            payload.setValidDragActor(validLabel);

            Label invalidLabel = new Label("Invalid!", skin);
            invalidLabel.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            payload.setInvalidDragActor(invalidLabel);


            return payload;
        }

    dragAndDrop.addTarget(new Target(actor) {
                public boolean drag (Source source, Payload payload, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                    getActor().setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    return true;
                }

                public void reset (Source source, Payload payload) {
                    getActor().setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

                public void drop (Source source, Payload payload, float x, float y, int pointer) {

                    int movingTile =((TileActor)source.getActor()).getPosition();
                    if(movingTile!=-1){
                int newPosition=player.moveTileOnBoard(movingTile, ((TileActor)getActor()).getPosition());

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you provide your own `Actor` to the `Payload` (so `DragAndDrop` take care about removing this actor):

```
payload.setDragActor(getActor());
```

Try to create the copy of the `Actor` instead:

```
Actor newActor = /* clone your actor from getActor() to newActor */;
payload.setDragActor(newActor);
```